# Firefox isn't filling print page after content is scaled down

Tags: css, firefox, printing, transform, scale

I'll do my best to explain this as I'm not able to show images because the information is not yet public.

I have a webpage that I am creating a sprint style for. I am trying to fit whole sections of content on pages using css transform scale because Firefox doesn't support the zoom property. All the content I'm scaling is in a container div.

This is the CSS I'm using:

```
#schoolprofile-container {
    transform: scale(.70);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    width: 140%;
```

This CSS as it is uses the full width of the print page, but I can't get it to use the full height of the print page, even if I apply a height property to the CSS. The content just cuts off to the next page, even when the bottom half of the print page is empty.

Does anyone know at all how to get Firefox to use the full width and height of the page so that I can fit my whole content on the one page?

I hope I've explained this well enough. If not, please ask me to clarify further.